# Why can not we call servlet constructor instead of init method to initialize the config parameters?

Tags: java, servlets

I like to know why dont we call servlet constructor instead of init method to initialize the config parameters.

THanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This thread should clarify the differences.](http://www.geekinterview.com/talk/6554-constructor-and-init.html)

Quoting from one of the more illuminating posts:

> The init() method is typically used to
>   perform servlet
>   initialization--creating or loading
>   objects that are used by the servlet
>   in the handling of its requests. Why
>   not use a constructor instead? Well,
>   in JDK 1.0 (for which servlets were
>   originally written), constructors for
>   dynamically loaded Java classes (such
>   as servlets) couldn't accept
>   arguments. So, in order to provide a
>   new servlet any information about
>   itself and its environment, a server
>   had to call a servlet's init() method
>   and pass along an object that
>   implements the ServletConfig
>   interface. Also, Java doesn't allow
>   interfaces to declare constructors.
>   This means that the
>   javax.servlet.Servlet interface cannot
>   declare a constructor that accepts a
>   ServletConfig parameter. It has to
>   declare another method, like init().
>   It's still possible, of course, for
>   you to define constructors for your
>   servlets, but in the constructor you
>   don't have access to the ServletConfig
>   object or the ability to throw a
>   ServletException.

Answer (score 3):

In general we can use constructor to perform initialization activities but in old version of java(JDK1.0v), constructor can not accept dynamically generated class name as argument. To perform initialization of a servlet compulsory we should provide ServletConfig object as an argument whose class name dynamically generated by web container , as constructor can’t accept the dynamically generated class names hence, sun people ignored the constructor concept and introduced a specific method init(-) to perform initialization activities which can take dynamically generated class name as an argument.